# Translation of "settling in"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, verbos

In English, "to settle in" describes what someone does after moving in to a new place or returning from a long vacation:

> I just got back, I'm still settling in.
>
> We moved last week! It will be a couple weeks until we're all settled in.

How does this concept translate to Spanish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Asentar(se)** seems the most apt word to me.

> I just got back, I'm still settling in.
>
> Recién regresé, todavía me estoy asentando. (or: estoy asentándome).

Other related words: **aclimatar(se)** (to adapt to new environments), **adaptar(se)**  (to adapt, in general), **acomodar(se)** (to make yourself confortable)

Comment: I don't think that's what "settle in" means in the context of the OP. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd translate it as **acomodándome**. Example:

> I just got back, I'm still settling in. --> Acabé de regresar, todavía
>   me estoy acomodando.
>
> We moved last week! It will be a couple weeks until we're all settled
>   in. --> ¡Nos pasamos la semana pasada!  Serán un par de semanas más
>   hasta que terminemos de acomodarnos

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "**instalarse**".

- I just got back, I'm still settling in. -> Acabo de volver, todavía me estoy instalando.
- We moved last week! It will be a couple weeks until we're all settled in. -> ¡Nos mudamos la semana pasada! Necesitaremos un par de semanas para instalarnos.

Comment: For the second one, I'd definitely use *instalarse*, but for the first, returning home, I'm not so sure. Though right now I can't think of a better alternative.